# как сделать аутентификации на свой сервер git по протоколу git daemon?

Tags: git

Поднял сервер через протокол git daemon на slakware. Нужно сделать авторизацию к этому серверу(репозиторию). Уже есть база отдельно с логинами и паролями пользователей. Пользователи могли бы пушить только на свою ветку, а админ пушить и создавать другие ветки.

Comment: Может стоит воспользоваться готовыми серверными решениями типа gitlab? Разворачиваете у себя и спокойно настраиваете доступ через web-админку

Comment: Если все возможности мощного gitlab не нужны, то и gitea может хватить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Протокол git daemon не имеет возможности авторизации, можно придумать костыли к нему, но для того что бы решить задачу с авторизаций, есть решение  использовать протокол http и через веб сервер реализовать авторизацию